# Why is -0.0 not the same as 0.0?

Tags: python, math, floating-point

I could be missing something fundamental, but consider this interpreter session<sup>1</sup>:

```
>>> -0.0 is 0.0
False
>>> 0.0 is 0.0
True
>>> -0.0  # The sign is even retained in the output.  Why?
-0.0
>>>
```

You would think that the Python interpreter would realize that `-0.0` and `0.0` are the same number.  In fact, it compares them as being equal:

```
>>> -0.0 == 0.0
True
>>>
```

So why is Python differentiating between the two and generating a whole new object for `-0.0`?  It doesn't do this with integers:

```
>>> -0 is 0
True
>>> -0  # Sign is not retained
0
>>>
```

Now, I realize that floating point numbers are a huge source of problems with computers, but those problems are always with regard to their accuracy.  For example:

```
>>> 1.3 + 0.1
1.4000000000000001
>>>
```

But this isn't an accuracy problem, is it?  I mean, we are talking about the sign of the number here, not its decimal places.

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>I can reproduce this behavior in both Python 2.7 and Python 3.4, so this is not a version-specific question.</sub>

Comment: I believe this is a feature of IEEE 754 floating point representation, which would mean it's not specific to Python either.

Comment: Integer overflow is probably a more serious "source of problems with computers."

Comment: Why are you using `is` for numeric comparisons?  Much of your question has little to do with signed zeros: try `x = 2.3`, `y = 2.3`, followed by `x is y`.  And then, just for fun, try `x = 2.3; y = 2.3` (all on one line), followed by `x is y`.

Comment: Following up on @MarkDickinson 's comment: There is a **very small** subset of literals where any variable you assign to them is just a pointer to where it *always* lives in memory. I am forgetting the reasoning, but it was something like, "a basic set of values will always be needed".  0, 1, 2, and a handful of other integers.  **Everything else** gets created.  Note: with `x = 2; y = 2` and `x is y`, you'll see `True`.  Try `x=-240000; y=-240000` and then `x is y`, and you'll see `False`. Hope that helps the next visitor!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In IEEE754, the format of floating point numbers, the sign is a separate bit. So -0.0 and 0.0 are different by this bit.
Integers use the two's complement, to represent negative numbers; that's why there is only one `0`.

Use `is` only of you really want to compare instances of objects. Otherwise, especially for numbers, use `==`:

```
>>> 1999+1 is 2000
False

>>> 0.0 == -0.0
True
```

Comment: I accept your answer because you explained both the float case as well as the integer one.  However, can you think of any real-world use cases for `-0.0`?  I know there are a few *theoretical* uses for it, but it really seems like it just gets in the way.

Comment: @iCodez: Signed zero is useful for the implementation of complex math functions. The canonical paper is: William Kahan, Branch Cuts for Complex Elementary Functions, or Much Ado About Nothing's Sign Bit. In: The State of the Art in Numerical Analysis, Clarendon Press, Oxford, 1987. Online copies are easily located via Google Scholar.

Comment: Note that Python doesn't specifically mandate IEEE-754. The [reference](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy) says "These represent machine-level double precision floating point numbers. You are at the mercy of the underlying machine architecture (and C or Java implementation) for the accepted range and handling of overflow." But on most platforms and implementations, that means IEEE-754 doubles, or something very close to it.

Comment: @njuffa: Also on Kahan's website.

Comment: Funny python lore: note that 10+1 is 11 returns True. The first 256 values (and some negative ones) are internalized, so you always get the same instance.

Comment: @StefanoBorini It seems something in Python has since changed.  I just toyed with this, and it seems your statement is true for *any* integers: `1500000 + 1 is 1500001` returns `True`.  Yet, `-0.0 is 0.0` still returns `False`.  I thought I understood `is`, but now I am confused again.  (I tried this on Python `3.7.6`.)

Answer (score 9):

The IEEE Standard for Floating-Point Arithmetic ([IEEE 754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point)) defines the inclusion of [signed zeroes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_zero). In theory they allow you to distinguish between negative number underflow and positive number [underflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_underflow).

As far as python specifically is concerned, use `==` rather than `is` to compare numbers.

Answer (score 4):

Because the binary representation of those two numbers is different.  In 0.0 the 32nd bit is 0 and in -0.0 the 32nd bit is 1.

Comment: Ok.  The answer still remains mostly the same.  The last bit in a float is the sign bit. 0 for positive 1 for negative.

Comment: Actually, in 2.x, floating-point numbers in Python are unspecified in general, and specified as "whatever `double` is in the C compiler used to build the interpreter" in CPython. In 3.x, they cleaned it up a bit and specified them as "a machine `double`" across implementations, but note that "You are at the mercy of the underlying machine architecture (and C or Java implementation)".